# GCP Terraform Apply and Destroy errors: oauth2: cannot fetch token: Post https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token: net/http: TLS handshake timeout

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I've been using GCP and Terraform for a few months - just creating some basic VMs and firewall resources for testing.

Increasingly, about 50% of the time when applying and 100% of the time when trying to destroy an environment using Terraform, I get the following error:

Error creating Firewall: Post https://www.googleapis.com/compute/beta/projects/mkdemos-219107/global/firewalls?alt=json: oauth2: cannot fetch token: Post https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token: net/http: TLS handshake timeout

To destroy, the only way is to log into the console, manually delete the resource and rm my local terraform state files.

Its the intermittent nature of this that is driving me crazy. I've tried creating a new project, re-creating a new json with service credentials and still the same behaviour.

If it consistently failed or had been doing this all the time, I'd assume there was something wrong in my Terraform template or the way I've setup the GCP Service Account. But sometimes it works - sometimes it doesn't - it makes no sense and is making using GCP unworkable for testing.

If anyone has any similar experience of this I'd welcome some thoughts. Surely it can't just be me?? ;-)

FYI:
Terraform: v0.11.7
provider.google: v1.19.0
Mac OSX: 10.13.1

Cheers.

Comment: This is almost certainly an environmental issue because you're failing to connect to an endpoint. Are you behind a proxy or do you have a non rock solid network connection? Whatever the case is, it's not something that you'll be able to get an answer from here and instead you'll need to investigate your own networking setup and potentially ask for help on a different Stack Exchange site (SuperUser might be a better fit if you can focus the question on your specific problem).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Its definitely not my network - its consistent at work and at home. Understood that is probably environmental to my machine somewhere though - being blocked for some reason. Will continue digging away. Thanks for responding.

Comment: did you fix it or found any pointer @JamesReynolds ?

Comment: Nope :-( Still get the same issue. Only way around (without doing a complete system re-install) was to create a Terraform VM in VirtualBox and run it from there. Works everytime. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

there might be a strange solution. please check that another user in your OS is able to do terraform commands. It means that problem is located in your user profile.

Finally, If it works then try backup and delete all certificates in your login keychain. Retry the terraform commands